# How to loop through array of classes with different types and print their properties in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, class

I am learning to work with classes and now I need to loop through array of classes with different types and print their properties.

It was not a problem, when there was only one super class and few subclasses, but problem occurred, when I added another superclass and it's subclasses. xCode told me to cast my array as [Any] and I lost my ability to rich class properties.

```
let human = People(name: "John Dou", height: 180, weight: 80, gender: "male") //every class inherits from class People this way
var peopleArray = [human, cook, manager, fighter] // this is an array of classes with type People

for person in peopleArray {
print(person.name, person.height, person.weight, person.gender)

person.say()
}
```

This for in loop works fine.

Then I created few classes, which inherits from class Marsian:

```
let martian = Martian(numberOfLegs: 1, planetOfBirth: "Mars")
```

Then I tried to put instances of every class in an array:

```
let unitedRaceArray = [martian, snikersian, twixian, austronaut, fighter, manager, cook, human]
```

But it shawed me an error: "Heterogeneous collection literal could only be inferred to '[Any]'; add explicit type annotation if this is intentional"

Of course, with type [Any], "for in" loop doesn't work.

Comment: I'd say that inside your for loop you can cast each item as? People or as? Marsian then you can access its properties

Comment: Martian please, not Marsian.

Comment: Casting each item helped, thank you, Samuel

Comment: @ArtemBoordak I'm pretty sure that modern Swift won't even let you do this: `var peopleArray = [human, cook, manager, fighter]`. You _must_ specify the common type of the array, explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
let unitedRaceArray: [People]
```

and you should be fine. If you want to access Martian's write

```
if let martian = person as? Martian {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift arrays are homogenous by default, if you need a heterogenous array you have to annotate the common type, this is what

> add explicit type annotation if this is intentional

means.

In the worst case annotate `[Any]` if the types are not related to each other at all.

With the given types in the question write

```
let unitedRaceArray : [Any] = [martian, human]
```

To iterate the array use a `switch` and *pattern match* the type

```
for individual in unitedRaceArray {
    switch individual {
        case let person as People:
            print(person.name)
        case let extraterrestrial as Martian:
            print(extraterrestrial.planetOfBirth)
        default: 
            print("unknown something")
    }
}
```